# how to decode content from blob?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

**How do we decode $content?**

My content:

[image]

When I simply do this:

[image]

I get this:

[image]

I've also tried this:

`body('Get_blob_content')['$content']`

that didn't work either:

[image]

another attempt:

`base64ToString(body('Get_blob_content')['$content'])`:

[image]

**How do we decode $content?**

Comment: I have a feeling you may not _want_ to decode that... it's an executable binary, specifically in Windows PE format.

Comment: Have you tried `decodeBase64(body('Get_blob_content')['$content'])`, the content should be encoded with base64.

Comment: And what's you file content, make sure your file content is a json string.

Comment: Hi, have you solved this problem ? If not, could you please provide some more details for the question asked by George Chen ?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with George Chen, the solution is **decodeBase64(body('Get_blob_content'))**, but you check if the content is a valid json in String format, if not, try to add string function:
**decodeBase64(string(body('Get_blob_content')))**.
Regards.